# i got this error: "ImportError: cannot import name python" How do I fix it?

Tags: python, pyamf

```
File "G:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PyAMF-0.6b2-py2.5-win32.egg\pyamf\util\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name python
```

How do I fix it?
If you need any info to know how to fix this problem, I can explain, just ask.

Thanks

Code:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from TottysGateway import TottysGateway
import logging

def main():
    services_root = 'services'
    #services = ['users.login']

    #gateway = TottysGateway(services, services_root, logger=logging, debug=True)

    #app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', gateway)], debug=True)

    #run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Code:

```
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.google import WebAppGateway
import logging


class TottysGateway(WebAppGateway):
    def __init__(self, services_available, root_path, not_found_service, logger, debug):
        # override the contructor and then call the super
        self.services_available = services_available
        self.root_path = root_path
        self.not_found_service = not_found_service
        WebAppGateway.__init__(self, {}, logger=logging, debug=True)

    def getServiceRequest(self, request, target):
        # override the original getServiceRequest method
        try:
            # try looking for the service in the services list
            return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            # don't know what it does but is an error for now
            service_func = self.router(target)
        except:
            if(target in self.services_available):
                # only if is an available service import it's module
                # so it doesn't access services that should be hidden
                try:
                    module_path = self.root_path + '.' + target
                    paths = target.rsplit('.')
                    func_name = paths[len(paths) - 1]
                    import_as = '_'.join(paths) + '_' + func_name
                    import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'
                    exec import_string
                except:
                    service_func = False

        if(not service_func):
            # if is not found load the default not found service
            module_path = self.rootPath + '.' + self.not_found_service
            import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'

        # add the service loaded above
        assign_string = "self.addService(service_func, target)"
        exec assign_string

        return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
```

Comment: You should also include the code where the error is happening.

Comment: Take a look in my updated question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post your full traceback. What you show here isn't all that useful. I ended up digging up line 15 of pyamf/util/**init**.py. The code you should have posted is

```
from pyamf import python
```

This should not fail unless your local environment is messed up.

Can you 'import pyamf.util' and 'import pyamf.python' in a interactive Python shell? What about if you start Python while in /tmp (on the assumption that you might have a file named 'pyamf.py' in the current directory. Which is a bad thing.)

= (older comment below) =

Fix your question. I can't even tell where line 15 of util/__init__.py is supposed to be. Since I can't figure that out, I can't answer your question. Instead, I'll point out ways to improve your question and code.

First, use the markup language correctly, so that all the code is in a code block. Make sure you've titled the code, so we know it's from util/__init__.py and not some random file.

In your error message, include the *full* traceback, and not the last two lines.

Stop using parens in things like "if(not service_func):" and use a space instead, so its "    if not service_func:". This is discussed in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Read the Python documentation and learn how to use the language. Something like "func_name = paths[len(paths) - 1]" should be "func_name = paths[-1]"

Learn about the [**import**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function and don't use "exec" for this case. Nor do you need the "exec assign_string" -- just do the "self.addService(service_func, target)"

Comment: Now I get it. I had to re install all.. thanks and sorry for this stupid question ;)